# Java Split String with 2 Tab

Tags: java, split

I got a problem with the java `split`, i want to split a string, which is divided with tabs:

```
String test = "1\t2\t\t4\t5";
String[] testArray = test.split("\\t+");
```

The content of the testArray is:

```
1
2
4
5
```

But i need following content in my array:

```
1
2

4
5
```

Comment: Maybe lose that `+` in the regular expression?

Comment: *....and now thee shall be blessed with spam of same answers posted over and again!!* :D

Comment: I dont think so you have tab in between 2 and 4 as above should work. Check your input. Also from your output i believe you want splitted by space as well?

Answer (score 4):

`\\t+` means "one or more", so, it matches both tabs at once. Try replacing it with just `\\t`.

Answer (score 3):

```
test.split("\\t+");
```

That `+` means: split at one **or more** tabs.

If you want to split at exactly one tab, you should just do

```
test.split("\\t");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the + in the regex.

```
String test = "1   2      4   5";
String[] testArray = test.split("\\t");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no character between the two tabs. That is why you are not getting it as a element in your array. Try inserting a space in between the two tabs and run. If you still insist on getting that extra space, use `split("\\t")`

Answer (score -2):

Try this code

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String test = "1   2      4   5";
        String[] testArray = test.split("\\t");

        for(int i=0;i<testArray.length;i++){
            System.out.println(testArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you mentioned is already told in 3 answers before you....expect possible downvote!

Comment: i tested time they will given the answer.

Comment: next time...test and type quickly and refresh page before posting! :)

Comment: what are you talking...man why are you given the down vote...your work is who is the give the answer.and edit that answer.@ NoobEditor

Comment: lol....no mate, i don't downvote answers...and i do have other roles than the ones which u mentioned :)